# ASP.NET Web API Sample Membership Authentication - Azure DB Initialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I created a brand new MVC 4 Project (using Web Api Template, not Internet template). How can I initialize the simple membership database at first run exactly as the internet template does? What I did so far:

- created brand new MVC 4 Project -> Web Api Template
- implemented the filter InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs and decorated the HomeController with it.
- added the model AccountModels.cs
- added enabled="true" attribute to roleManager under system.web in web.config
- the connection string is pointing to SQL Azure and working fine

When I run this app for the first time, the database is created but are created just 1 table in it: UserProfile, all the other tables: webpages_Membership, webpages_Roles ... are missing. There are no errors nothing.

All I need is to be able that when my MVC4 Project (Web Api Template) runs for the first time, will ensure that the SampleMembership db and tables are created. In order to be able to authenticate a client rest call using membership authentication.

Please let me know if this is the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the connection string name in the web.config is defined

- in AccountModels.cs for the usercontext
- in InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs for the database initialization